# Constraints programming in java

Tags: java, constraint-programming

How to develope  an efficent job scheduling with constraints??

The scheduler should include these methods:

```
startBeforeEndOf(Job j)
startAfterEndOf(Job j)
startBeforeStartOf(Job j)
startAfterStartOf(Job j)
endBeforeEndOf(Job j)
endAfterEndOf(Job j)
endBeforeStartOf(Job j)
endAfterStartOf(Job j)
```

Every job has an id and the time parameter.

A possible solution for this matter, may be based on technical backtracking. The jobs are used as choice points, and temporal instants as choices (in the worst case the total duration of the activity is the sum of the durations of the work, resulting in a fully sequential execution).

Alternatively I should adequately represent the data and then generates a scheduling on the time axis, placing the work under the constraints and moving forward in a job (and all the jobs that depend on it) when a constraint is not satisfied.
 But I don't know how exactly I can do this in java.

In other words I looking for a way to avoiding the intense backtracking approach, in the job management described.

Comment: Is this homework? Do you know any algorithms that could be used for this? You could add heuristics in your search process but backtracking seems part of the solution either way. Unless you wish to go for exhaustive search of course :-)

Comment: I'm thinking to use various list to separate each job according his constraint for example private List<Job> startBeforeEnd;
 private List<Job> startAfterEnd;
 private List<Job> startBeforeStart;
 private List<Job> startAfterStart;
 private List<Job> endBeforeEnd;
 private List<Job> endAfterEnd;
 private List<Job> endBeforeStart;
 private List<Job> endAfterStart;
 private List<Job> restricted; BUT I don't know how exactly can develop this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org) (java, open source). There is [a quick start here](https://hudson.jboss.org/hudson/view/Drools%20jBPM/job/drools-planner/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/drools-planner-docs/target/docbook/publish/en-US/html_single/index.html#quickStart).

For example, assign each `Job` to a `startMinute`, then add score rules like:

```
when
    $leftJob : Job($startMinute : startMinute)
    // getEndMinute() returns startMinute + durationInMinutes
    $rightJob : Job(beforeJob == $leftJob, endMinute > $startMinute)
then
    // punish
end
```

Comment: emmm... could you give me more details, how adapt drools to meet the solution at this problem??? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use an open source constraint programming library. [This](http://www.manageability.org/blog/stuff/open-source-constraint-programming-java) post points to many solvers written in Java for constraint satisfaction problems and more.

Comment: Thanks but these libraries are too big for this specific problem, Is there something smaller?

Comment: @AndreaF - Not that I'm aware of. But you can find the functionality you need from one of the libraries. Then dig into the library's implementation and adapt it to your case.

Comment: Read hundred codelines ad try to adapt these generic libraries at this problem Is a too complicated way. 
With a right intuition I think this could be resolved by a skilled developer in a couple of little class.